# Is there a way to see a report of auth'd Google accounts to a my API Key?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I'm looking to see if anyone knows of a way to see a count of accounts authorized to my API key for the Gmail API or any Google API in the console in general. TIA

Answer (score 0):

No such feature mentioned in [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). If you have suspicion of other people using your API key, you can always generate a new one and keep it privately.

In your developer console, you can select the traffic per credentials. This report will only give you an overview of the traffic but not on specific count of user authenticated.

Comment: Thanks so much. I figured as much. I was trying to see if there was a way for me to pull number of people who have auth'd through my service from Google but I guess I'll have to keep track of that on my end. Appreciate your time.